# "Delegate" a class to inside a method

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
Calculator cl = new Calculator();
```

And I have a class with a method:

```
public class Testing {
  public void Calc(int x) {
  }
}
```

I would like to delegate a Calculator to the Calc method so it can be used inside Calc.

Does this make sense? How can I do this?

Comment: You mean like pass it as a parameter? `public void Calc( int x, Calculator calc )`

Comment: Well, yes but I was thinking in sending using a Func or Action. I am not sure if that is possible ... Something like "use this".

Comment: @MDMoura: Well a delegate is for a *single* piece of code. We've no idea what you've got in `Calculator`, but it could have many methods - which are you trying to pass to `Calc`? Perhaps actually `Calculator` should implement an interface? We need more context.

Comment: This seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want to be able to *use* a calculator within the `Testing` class, have a reference to a calculator instance within the `Testing` type (e.g. a private field storing it, which you assign in the constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svick's answer is entirely correct and more appropriate for the problem you describe.  But since you mention delegates, here's how you might use one in the context of your example:

```
public static class Testing
{
    public static long Calc(long x, long y, Func<long, long, long> function)
    {
        if (function == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
        return function(x, y);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Func<long, long, long> add = delegate(long a, long b) { return a + b; };
        Func<long, long, long> multiply = (a, b) => a * b;

        Console.WriteLine("3+2 = {0}", Calc(3, 2, add);
        Console.WriteLine("6*7 = {0}", Calc(6, 7, multiply);
        Console.WriteLine("3^2 = {0}", Calc(3, 2, (a, b) => Math.Pow(a, b));
    }
}
```

This is a rather silly application of [delegates](http://www.dotnetperls.com/delegate) and lambdas, but it does reveal a glimpse of their power.

Comment: "delegate" has multiple definitions.  He's not using that definition of the word.

Comment: "I was thinking in sending using a Func or Action. I am not sure if that is possible" - MDMoura

Comment: That's a comment, which granted, I didn't see, but the use of the word "delegate" in the question is not consistent with the the definition of the term in C#.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell what exactly are you asking. But if the `Calculator` class represents some sort of “service” the `Testing` class is meant to be using, then the common way is to use a field:

```
public class Testing
{
  private readonly Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

  public void Calc(int x)
  {
    // use calculator here
  }
}
```

If `Calculator` is actually configurable, or something like that, and you don't want to initialize it inside `Testing`, then you can take it as a constructor parameter:

```
public class Testing
{
  private readonly Calculator calculator;

  public Testing(Calculator calculator)
  {
    this.calculator = calculator;
  }

  public void Calc(int x)
  {
    // use calculator here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find delegate types useful. They avoid the `Func<int, int, int>`-everywhere trap. If the signature of the function changes it makes it easier to modify the existing code.

You can also make the delegate itself a property.

```
public class Testing {
    // this is the signature of the method we'd like to use to calculate.
    public delegate int Calculator(int a, int b);

    public Calculator Calc { get; set; }

    public Testing() {
        this.Calc = (x, y) => {
            throw new Exception("You haven't set a calculator!");
        };
    }

    public Testing(Calculator calc) {
        this.Calc = calc;
    }

    public int CalcWithOne(int x) {
        return Calc(1, x);
    }
}
```

Then you can just use like

```
Testing test = new Testing((x, y) => x + y);
// or
Testing test = new Testing();
test.Calc = (x, y) => x + y;
// then
test.Calc(2, 3); // 5
test.CalcWithOne(7); // 8
```